# Optimal implementation of function in terms of performance

Tags: java, optimization

I have a list of items and a map that is stores the information about the product and it's items data. There are around 150k items in the DB and around 200k products (each product has approximately 1000 to 2000 items that mapped to it).

I need a function that counts amount of products each item appears in. This is the function that I have implemented:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getProductsNumberForItem(List<Item> itemsList,
        Map<Integer, Map<Item, Integer>> itemsAmount) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Item i : itemsList) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Map<Item, Integer> entry : itemsAmount.values()) {
            if (entry.containsKey(i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        result.put(i.getID(), count);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine on my test DB, which has small amount of data, but when I run it on real data, it takes too much time (for ex.: it has been running already for an hour and still is not finished). From logical point of view its clear, that I am basically performing too many operations, but not sure how can I optimize.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a relational DB? If you are then you should be able to do most of the work there.

Comment: Push the aggregation to the database.

Comment: @mrmcgreg yes, just that got into my mind, that I can just retrieve the size of set of mapped products.

Comment: @AndrewS it is already there. Totally forgot about that using proper mapping its simple to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways :

- most efficient : do the computation in a query executed in the database.
  With `count()` aggregate and `group by` clause, you should get a much better result as the whole processing will be performed by the DBMS that is designed/optimized to do it.
- less efficient but you may give it a try: retrieve the data as now and use multi-threading.
  With Java 8 `parallelStream()`, you could maybe get an acceptable result without the hassle to handle synchronization yourself.

Comment: I have already implemented it, by just correcting the mappings inside entities. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem. However, if the relationship is lazy, it will perform a distinct query for each product. It is not efficient.

Comment: Oh, I did not specify, if it is loaded eagerly or lazy. Is it possible to identify how is the setup by default?

Comment: By default, it is lazy for *-to-many relationships. Look at  fetch attribute in the *toMany annotation Doing it eager will still be expensive in memory and could also be not optimal in terms of executed queries. You should enable the Hibernate SQL logs and monitor them.

Comment: will give a try with eager, parallelization and then at the end with queries =)

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to delegate this computation to the db, avoiding the need to transfer all data to your application server.

If this is not an option, then for sure you can improve your current algorithm. Right now, for each item on the list, you are looping through all products; that's exponential cost.

you could do that (using streams since ressoning is easier to follow in my opinion and also allows for adding some improvements; but same could be achieved without them):

```
Stream<Item> productsItemsStream = itemsAmount.values().stream().flatMap(p -> p.keySet().stream());
Map<Item,Long> countByItemFound = productsItemsStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
Map<Integer, Integer> result = itemsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getID, i -> countByItemFound.getOrDefault(i.getID(), 0L).intValue()));
```

With this approach you will do one full pass to product items. And then another pass to items list. That's linear cost.

Specificto streams, you could give a try to enable parallelism (adding parallelStream to my solution), but it's not completely granted to have big performance increase; depends on several factors. I would wait to see performance on proposed solution and, if needed, profile performance with and without parallelStream in your scenario.